# How can i run apache2 on EC2 Amazon Debain?

Tags: linux, debian, apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, port

I want to install apache2 on EC2 Amazon instance and access it from internet .
I have installed apache2 sucessfully using command

> apt-get install acache2

After that I checked status of apache2 and it gives me that apache2 is running.
Than I tried to get my web pages from browser ,but I am not able to access that using

> http://X-X-X-X-X.compute-1.amazonaws.com

How can I access that web pages using browser?

Waiting forward for reply.

Thanks

Comment: I have only access of ssh.How can i check and open that using SSH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you open port on your security group 80 check on following url

http://studyhat.blogspot.com/2010/08/using-amazon-web-services.html

Comment: I have only access of ssh.How can i check and open that using SSH?

Comment: Prakash that is in side your box what you need to is goto aws management console once you login to you account goto Security Groups check that out port 80

Comment: http://www.dropmocks.com/mMt_L look at the screen shot